# ASP.NET 6 Lambda microservices: how to interchange data?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices

I am developing ASP.NET 6 Lambda. During the development I have decided to separate 1 NET 6 Lambda service to N smaller NET 6 Lambda microservices.

How to implement data interchange  between these microservices? I.e. connection strings, some  other data, microservice 1 calls microservice2 and pass some data? Also, how to and where to store  microservices urls to have a possibility lambda microservice1 calls microserviceN?